# Maven tomcat7 plugin starts app but is not accessible remotely

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Java application using the maven tomcat7 plugin.

I ran

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

And it was successful. But I can't access the application remotely.

This was part of the log:

```
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/cerberus
```

And I tried accessing **IP:8080/cerberus**, getting a "No webpage was found for the web address" error.

How can I make it work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your port 8080 for outside network requests to access it.

If you're on Windows, here is how you can do that: http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-3114787/open-firewall-ports-windows.html

Comment: It should be open already - since I'm using a ubuntu vm from DigitalOcean. How can I check?

Comment: You must check again if your port is open. See this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cannot-open-port-8080

Comment: It is open. If I run python3 -m http.server 8080 it is accessible remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you **IP** is not a "outside ip" or you webapp not deploy success.

First ,you should check if you can get success from remote computer by **ping**

then ,check if you can access you webapp on localhost and the a computer which in the same LAN with the server.

Comment: I know **IP** is a outside IP, since it is the one I use to ssh in. 

How can I know if it did deploy successfully if the machine is not mine? It's from DigitalOcean and I just ssh in.

Comment: w3m does return me the website if I access http:0.0.0.0/path. So it did deploy (to 0.0.0.0)

Comment: you got me on this situation. Can you also access website using  **IP** :8080/cerberus(not 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1) by w3m?

Comment: Inside or outside ssh?

Comment: Inside . ssh in and use **ip**:8080/cerberus try again

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that ufw was the culprit. Even though the port was allowed through it, it somehow was not letting outer connections in. I disabled it and used iptables instead.